# How does the typecasting mechanism work in PHP during division of different types of numbers?

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

I've following code snippet :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <?php
      $x = 10;  
      $y = 6;

      echo $x / $y;
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Output of the above program is `1.6666666666667`

I was expecting the output to be **1(i.e. an integer value)** as I'm dividing two integer values. But, I got surprised to see that the output I got is a **decimal fraction value**.

Can someone please explain in simple, lucid and easy to understand language why did I get decimal fraction value as output in above program?

That is, how did the typecasting work in above program?

Also, explain the typecasting mechanism when division of two fractions or one fraction and one integer is done **with working code examples**.

Also, let me know does the typecasting to fraction value is necessary only in case of division or in other arithmetic operations too(i.e.addition, subtraction and multiplication) it's needed. If yes, how does it work? If no, what's the valid reason behind it?

Thank You.

Comment: The type of the input operands does not determine the type of the result, as simple as that. If the result is a fraction, you get a float. No more, no less.

Comment: @deceze: Are you saying that no typecasting is done and whatever the types of operand are(i.e. integer or float) irrespective of that I will always get float value as result?

Comment: I'm saying that `10 / 2` results in an `int`, while `10 / 6` results in a `float`.

Comment: @deceze: I want the actual reason why I don't get an int result for the expression 10/6?

Comment: Because the result of `10 / 6` isn't an integer in the mathematical sense and can only be represented by a `float`.

Comment: @deceze:If such is the case then why in C language I get int result for the same calculation 10/6 and as per my knowledge PHP parser has also been written in C language?

Comment: It doesn't matter what something is written in. PHP made the decision to do it this way, period.

Comment: Just because PHP is written in C doesn't mean it has to work the exact same way. See also: the countless other ways in which the languages are different.

Comment: @iainn: Then I would say that this is abnormal behavior that is present in PHP and it has to be accepted that this is a Bug in PHP. Can we say this?

Comment: Why? PHP decided on this behaviour. You can frame it as not wanting to lose precision, regardless of the type of inputs. That's not a bug, that's a design decision.

Comment: @deceze: Ok sir, alright. I'm not as much big expert of PHP as you are sir. Thanks for sharing your thoughts and helping me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, it's a bit muddy in PHP - it's not purely down to either the operator or the operands. [As per the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

> The division operator ("/") returns a float value unless the two operands are integers (or strings that get converted to integers) and the numbers are evenly divisible, in which case an integer value will be returned. For integer division, see intdiv().

So you'll get a `float` back unless both the operands are integers **and** they are exactly divisible.

```
<?php
var_dump(10 / 5);
var_dump(10.0 / 5.0);
var_dump(10 / 4);

int(2)
float(2)
float(2.5)
```

Comment: Holy crap... I know the response is gonna be "welcome to PHP lol", but this is mind-bendingly terrible design. You get such bizarre cases as `((int) $n / 2) / ((int) $n / 2)` giving `int(1)` if `$n` is 10, but `float(1)` if `$n` is 11 